# Prevent pivot table from counting zeroes in the data

Tags: excel, count, pivot-table

I have a database with yearly revenue of clients. I counting number of clients via pivot table for each year. But it is counting clients with 0 revenues as well which I don't want

Created a pivot table with Revenues as sum and no. of clients with count function but the pivot is calculating clients with 0 revenues as well which is bumping up the no. of clients

Comment: Use countifs() and a constraint that revenue >0.

Comment: I want to do it in pivot only